# What is wrong with my javascript imacro code

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, imacros

I tried writing writing a script for imacros in javascript. However, it doesn't work. When I press play, it just does nothing. No error, no nothing. I had a imacro script a friend gave me (javascript imacro), that works, but mine doesn't. Can any body tell me what I am doing wrong.

PS: I am a beginner coder.

My code:

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:"; 
macro +="SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 2" + "\n";
macro +="URL GOTO=LINK_TO_SITE" + "\n";
macro +="EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35" + "\n";
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n";
macro +="EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35" + "\n";
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n";

var macro1;
macro1 = "CODE:";
macro1 +="TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Open<SP>Link" + "\n";

var macro2;
macro2 = "CODE:";
macro2 +="TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Create<SP>Link" + "\n";

var macro3;
macro3 = "CODE:";
macro3 +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:View<SP>More" + "\n";

var macro4;
macro4 = "CODE:";
macro4 +="WAIT SECONDS=180" + "\n";

iimPlay(macro)

var i = 11;
while (i > 0) {

    iimSet("i",i)
    iimPlay(macro1)

    var j = 1;
    while (j <= 61) {

        iimSet("j", j)
        iimPlay(macro2)

        if (j % 30 == 0) {

            iimPlay(macro3)
        }

        if (j == 60) {

            iimPlay(macro4)
        }

        j++;
    }

    i--;
}
```

Comment: Is this correct: `var i = 11; while (i < 11) {`? The `while` will never start. `i` is `11` and you loop while `i` is lower than `11`, so this will never happen in this example ...

Comment: @eisbehr Now i get this error: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line NaN (Error code: -991)`. Error -991 means `Javascript parsing/evaluation error`

Comment: I don't know if `imacros` has problems with missing semicolon. So add them behind your function calls, like `iimSet("i",i);`.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying in your while `While(i < 11)` but `i == 11` so it won't work and your while will never loop. You need to process like that :

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:"; 
macro +="SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 2" + "\n";
macro +="URL GOTO=LINK_TO_SITE" + "\n";
macro +="EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35" + "\n";
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n";
macro +="EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35" + "\n";
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n";

var macro1;
macro1 = "CODE:";
macro1 +="TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Open<SP>Link" + "\n";

var macro2;
macro2 = "CODE:";
macro2 +="TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Create<SP>Link" + "\n";

var macro3;
macro3 = "CODE:";
macro3 +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:View<SP>More" + "\n";

var macro4;
macro4 = "CODE:";
macro4 +="WAIT SECONDS=180" + "\n";


var i = 11;
while (i > 0) {

    iimSet("i",i)
    iimPlay(macro1)

    var j = 1;
    while (j <= 61) {

        iimSet("j", j)
        iimPlay(macro2)

        if (j % 30 == 0) {

            iimPlay(macro3)
        }

        if (j == 60) {

            iimPlay(macro4)
        }

        j++;
    }

    i--;
}
```

Comment: I fixed that part, now i get a `Javascript parsing/evaluation error`